# C, Expression must be a modifiable lvalue (changing the value of a struct's member)

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm an extreme newbie, I'm just trying to learn.. this is my simple struct that I've created

```
struct Student{
char FirstName[20];
char LastName[20];
char StudentID[10];
char Password[20];}
```

Then I'm creating an array of pointers;

```
struct Student *StudentList[10];
```

I am then calling my "Register" function and passing the first element in the array as a parameter, for the reason of changing values to that specific struct element in the array, for example I want to change the student's details;

```
Register(&StudentList[0]);
```

Further on, my function;

```
void Register(struct Student *student);
void Register(struct Student *student) {student->FirstName = "John";}
```

This is a very simplified example and sorry for not being able to correctly paste in the code here.

But why am I getting an "expression must be a modifiable lvalue", when I try to assign a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign array types like that in C, and `"John"` is an array of type `char[5]`.

```
strcpy(student->FirstName, "John");
```

would do it or, better still, something of the form

```
strncpy(student->FirstName, "John", 20);
```

so you avoid overrunning the `char` buffer.

Answer (score 2):

The `firstName` field is an array, and arrays cannot be assigned to as a whole.  That's what the error message is telling you.

Since you're copying a string into this array, you should use `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(student->FirstName, "John");
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, you do not set strings using `=` (and you do not compare them using `==` either).

You must use the `strcpy` function:

```
strcpy( student->firstName, "John" );
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you forget to put semicolon at the end of struct declaration `struct Student { };`

Secondly, you are passing `&StudentList[0]`, instead just pass `StudentList[0]` and allocate memory dynamically for that first.

Finally, `student->FirstName = "John";`  because `student->FirstName` is one char buffer and `"John"` also one buffer so you can't do `A = B` where `A` and `B` both are `char buffer`, instead use `strcpy(A,B);`

Here is sample example

```
struct Student{
        char FirstName[20];
        char LastName[20];
        char StudentID[10];
        char Password[20];
}; /* you forget to put semicolon */
void Register(struct Student *student)  {
        strcpy(student->FirstName,"John"); /* use strcpy() */
        printf("%s\n",student->FirstName);
}
int main() {
        struct Student *StudentList[10];
        for(int index = 0;index < 10;index++) {
        StudentList[index] = malloc(sizeof(struct Student)); /* allocate memory for each Student */
        }
        Register(StudentList[0]);

        /* free the dynamically allocated memory */

        return 0;
}
```